# Should I use pact based stub service or Wiremock.net?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, microservices, wiremock, pact-net

I am researching tools for [Component Testing](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/#testing-component-introduction/) for Microservices in the dotnetcore world.

Along with Component Testing I am planning to do [Contract Testing](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/#testing-contract-introduction) as well using Pact.net.

While reading Pact.net here:
https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net

I found link to:
https://github.com/seek-oss/seek.automation.stub
which says its a Pact based stubbing library for .NET.
This makes lot of sense to use since I am going to use Pact and my Pacts can be used for stubbing.

But before this I was considering WireMock.net https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net. Has anyone tried each and share their feedback which one I should pick? WireMock seems to be very popular in community compared to this Seek Automation stub.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: At [so] we aim to help people with concrete programming difficulties. This means that questions should at the very least contain a specific problem. The question you're asking in the [tag:wiremock] should be about a specific issue and not be principally about held opinions. If you want to know more about what makes a good question for [so] please have a look at the section: [ask].

Comment: @A. Kootstra sorry my question was not specific. I was not asking about opinions I was asking about experience people who have used and tried either of the tools. But anyways I understand your concern, please close my question as not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

You could ask this on the Pact gitter channel https://gitter.im/realestate-com-au/pact

Comment: Thanks Beth this is helpful.

Comment: I am planning to use pact provided stub server for most of my tests instead of using wiremock. Just because of the faster ramp up time to get the stub server up and running. I found out how easily I can provide the pact json files to the pact stub server library and I don't need to create json files manually. Just added this for someone else looking for same answer.